# Representations and Vector Bundles over the Classifying Space

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, representation-theory, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I'm merely trying to understand the following statement I came across while reading.

[image]

The text doesn't provide a reference or a recap of the construction that explains this fact. I'm adequately versed in the definitions of representation, Lie group, and vector bundle, so probably I don't understand the classifying space $BG$ sufficiently well to know how this would work. If anyone could elucidate I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Lie group $G$, one has the principal $G$-bundle $G\hookrightarrow EG\to BG$ over the classifying space $BG$. In this case, $EG$ is a right $G$-space, and a representation $\rho:G\to\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ gives $\mathbb{C}^n$ a left action of $G$ by:
$$g\cdot v := (\rho(g))(v).$$
Now, form the *associated bundle* $EG\times_G\mathbb{C}^n\to BG$ as follows: $EG\times_G\mathbb{C}^n$ is defined as the quotient space:
$$EG\times_G\mathbb{C}^n := \frac{EG\times\mathbb{C}^n}{(x,v)\sim (x\cdot g,g^{-1}\cdot v)}$$
The map $EG\times\mathbb{C}^n\xrightarrow{\ \pi_1 \ }EG\xrightarrow{\ p \ }BG$ factors through $EG\times_G\mathbb{C}^n$ giving a map:
$$\bar{p}:EG\times_G\mathbb{C}^n\to BG,\quad \bar{p}[x,v] = p(x).$$
In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439177/how-to-prove-local-trivialization-of-fiber-bundle-associated-to-principal-bundle/2450618#2450618) I explain how to obtain the trivializations.

As a quick example, if you take $U(1)=S^1$ to be your Lie group, then the classifying space $BU(1)$ is the Grassmanian $\operatorname{Gr}_1(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})=\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$, and $EU(1)$ is the Stiefel manifold $V_1(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$. If we take our representation to be the inclusion $\rho:U(1)\hookrightarrow\operatorname{GL}_1(\mathbb{C})$, then the associated bundle $EU(1)\times_{U(1)}\mathbb{C}$ is precisely the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$. In fact, the pullback of $EU(1)\to \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ over the inclusion $i:\mathbb{CP}^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ is the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^n$.

Comment: Okay, I think I was forgetting that there's an $EG$ over $BG$ which is a principal bundle (the associated bundle construction I'm perfectly fine with). I think maybe I should read more about what these universal objects actually are, though I seem to recall Milnor's construction is some kind of infinite join and that's about the point I stopped reading (this was many years ago now, when I was less wise...).

Comment: @BrianKlatt If you'd like a reference [these notes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwjUpcjc4sfaAhXhUN8KHTCDB8AQFghcMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww3.nd.edu%2F~mbehren1%2F18.906%2Fprin.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2n-YyBsQyTF64bHbmHqioC) are good.